# Why does the energy-balance equation imply convergence if the energy function is bounded from below?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

In "Modeling and Control of Complex Physical Systems – The Port-Hamiltonian Approach" on p. 273-275 input-state-output port-Hamiltonian systems are examined.

These are of the form
$$ \begin{cases} \dot x = [J(x) - R(x)] \frac{\partial H}{\partial x} (x) + g(x)u + k(x)d \\ y = g^T(x) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x) \\ z = k^T(x) \frac{\partial H}{\partial x}(x)\end{cases} $$

Where $J(x) = -J^T(x), R(x) = R^T(x) \geq 0$.
(In the case I'm interested in, $u = y = d = z = 0$.)

The energy-balance equation for such a system is given by
$$ H(x(t)) - H(x(0)) = \int_0^t u^T(s) y(s)~\mathrm{d}s - d(t)$$
where $H$ is the system's hamiltonian function and $d(t)$ is a non-negative function capturing dissipative effects.

It is stated that:

> The energy of the uncontrolled system (i.e. with $u \equiv 0$) is non-increasing (that is, $H(x(t)) \leq H(x(0))$) and it will actually decrease in the presence of dissipation.
> If the energy function is bounded from below, the system will eventually stop at a point of minimum energy.

While the first part of that statement is clear to me, I can't figure out, why the statement about the convergence holds.

The same statement is also found in [Putting Energy Back in Control](https://www.rug.nl/research/portal/files/14403036/2001IEEEContSystMagOrtega.pdf) on page 4 of the pdf.

Comment: Are there maybe cases which are only slightly more restricted, but where this may be shown somewhat easily?

Comment: Could you please better explain what is not clear? If the system is uncontrolled, the energy function is nonincreasing. If the function has a predefined minimum value (i.e., it is bounded from below), such nonincreasing function will necessarily reach that minimum level, sooner or later. In this case,  the system
will stop at this point.

Comment: Even if the system has dissipative effects in some states, I.e. $d(x)> 0$ there, this does not have to be true for all states. I don't see what prevents the state oscillating on a set of points, which all have the same energy level, but none of which are a minimum.

Comment: You are right. Surely there can be states with $d(x)=0$, in which the system oscillates around points with the same energy. The convergence towards the minimum should not be interpreted as a continuous decrease. In this regard, also note the word "eventually" used in the text that you cited. On the other hand, in the real systems, it is know that dissipative effects play relevant roles 
and that states with zero dissipation are not so common.

Comment: Do you still have doubts regarding convergence? Let me know whether you need further explanations.

Comment: Honestly, I feared that there might not really be a guarantee.
It is obvious that we may not even guarantee dissipativity everywhere (definitely not in a minimum).
However I find it a bit sad to see multiple sources using this as if this was the case.

So well, I feel like I have to stick to my own analysis for my particular application instead of just referring to this statement and acting as if everything was okay :D